# Unity: Switch between set of images after pressing button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, game-engine, game-development

On my UI I have an image which has to be updated as soon as I press a certain key (e.g. the heart image is changed to a coin image). In this case I just want to try to call the method by using

`Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow);`

I don't want to press a button on the UI. Now I want to switch between to images but I don't know how I can reference between the two images. I saw solutions like these:

`currentImage.sprite = newImage;`

My sprites are not really images but I don't want to create images out of them. Do I have to do it or can I do it with the sprites? And what other solutions are there?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by your sprites are not images. But you should be able to assign a sprite to your UI image element.

Here is a sample

```
public Sprite my_sprite;
public Image img;

void Update() 
{     
  if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))   
  {           
    img.sprite=my_sprite;   
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!
If I use your solution it would be only possible to switch it into "one direction". I want it to make possible to change the image back to the original one if you press the button again.

Comment: You can declare another variable of type sprite and save your original image to that. Set a Boolean to true when the new image is set and check for it when the key is presses next time to set the old image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public Sprite heartSprite;    
public Sprite coinSprite;
public Image img;
void Update()
{
    bool isPressed = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow);
    img.sprite = isPressed ? coinSprite : heartSprite;
}
```